# Is there a public Google Compute Engine Image with Tensorflow + gpu + Python 3.6

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've tried a number of the compute engine debian tensorflow images here https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#os-compute-support and they all seem to be Python 3.5.

1. Is there a google public image with Tensorflow + gpu + Python 3.6?
2. How can I tell what version of Python is in the google public image without actually creating it?

Thanks,
Melissa

Comment: I'm specifically interested in Google's public images for compute engine.

Answer (score 0):

You might be confusing public images with deployments in the Marketplace.

Public images are provided and maintained by Google, open-source communities, and third-party vendors. By default, all projects have access to these images and can use them to create instances. [1]

These images are the basic OS (OS images tab) and Windows servers with SQL installed (Application images).

If you are referring to solutions in the Marketplace I found the solution “AISE TensorFlow NVidia GPU Production” that has a NVIDIA Tesla P100 GPU with the following packages installed:

- TensorFlow 1.10.0
- TensorFlow 1.8.0
- TensorFlow 1.7.0
- TensorFlow 1.6.0
- TensorFlow 1.5.0
- Python 3.6.3
- Python 2.7.14
- CUDA 9.2.148.1
- CUDA 9.1.85.3
- CUDA 9.1.85.1
- CUDA 9.0.176
- cuDNN 7.2.1
- cuDNN 7.1.3
- cuDNN 7.1.2
- cuDNN 7.0.5

To answer your question to tell if it has the Python version you need without deploying it you can see it in the “Package contents” section (bottom left corner) when you inspect the solution in the Marketplace but it will depend on the publisher providing this information.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the confusion.  My question is specifically concerning Google's public images so my questions are still unanswered.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.

You must be referring to the images optimized for TPU (eg “Debian GNU/Linux 9 Stretch + TF 1-11”).

1) I found that they have Python 3.5


2) Sadly, there is no way to determine the Python version without creating the device. 

I recommend you add a startup script to install python 3.6 during the creation of the VM [1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_startup_script_contents_directly